# Annotating a PDF presentation with a Wacom graphics tablet in Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, presentation, tablet

Usually I use Evince to show a PDF beamer presentation and I use Xournal to annotate the PDF with handwritten notes using a Wacom tablet.

Is there a software for Linux where I can combine both, i.e. annotate with the Wacom tablet on a PDF beamer presentation *in presentation mode*?

Answer (score 3):

If by "annotate" you mean "draw", Okular can do that in presentation mode, but the annotations are ephemeral.

> Click on the `Toggle Drawing Mode` icon in the top bar to enable or disable the possibility to draw in the presentation mode. The drawings are cleared automatically when leaving the presentation mode. You can also click on the `Erase Drawings` icon to remove the drawings in the current page.

https://docs.kde.org/trunk4/en/kdegraphics/okular/presentationMode.html

By the way, presentation mode for Xournal has been requested at least twice since 2009.

https://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/feature-requests/75/

https://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/feature-requests/167/

Comment: Sounds great. Is it also possible to save the document with the drawing?

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There are two more answers to this question:

1. Use the **Full Screen** mode of Xournal: *View* --> *Full Screen*. In addition, turn on **One Page** view: *View* --> *One Page*.

   If you want to get rid of the toolbars, you have to manually edit `~/.xournal/config` (in case it is not existing, simply save your configuration from within Xournal: *Options* --> *Save Preferences*). Look for the following line:

   `interface_fullscreen=main_toolbar pen_toolbar drawarea`

   Change it to

   `interface_fullscreen=drawarea`

   I recently found this very helpful tip in a [youtube-video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tncWv1BRfxY).
2. My preferred way is to use [Xournalpp](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp), which is based on Xournal but contains a lot of additional features, including a presentation mode in which you can simply switch-off all annoying toolbars. You can install it on Ubuntu via

   `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andreasbutti/xournalpp-master`

   `$ sudo apt update`

   `$ sudo apt install xournalpp`